# Appending JSON objects children into each div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on the following demo. How can I load/append each days `[day-1, day-2, day-3, day-3]` players wrapped in a `<span>` into the `.card-body` as needed? So in this case only four `card-body`must loaded.

```js
var cars = {
  "day-1": {
    "player-1-1": "Ford",
    "player-1-2": "BMW"
  },
  "day-2": {
    "player-2-1": "Benz",
    "player-2-2": "KIA",
  },
  "day-3": {
    "player-3-1": "Toyota",
    "player-3-2": "Mazda",
  },
  "day-4": {
    "player-4-1": "Honda",
    "player-4-2": "Nissan",
  },
}

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(cars).forEach((val, index) => {
  var txt = Object.values(cars[val]);
  console.log(txt);
})
```

```css
span {
  background: orange;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body"></div>
<div class="card-body"></div>
<div class="card-body"></div>
<div class="card-body"></div>
<div class="card-body"></div>
<div class="card-body"></div>
<div class="card-body"></div>
<div class="card-body"></div>
```

Comment: What should the output be? Inside each `card-body`, should there be `day-1`, `day-2`, or should there be `Ford,BMW`, `Benz,KIA`...What should the HTML result be?

Comment: That would be great to have both I will know how to get each

Comment: OK I've answered, does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Just append the HTML string to the body:

```js
var cars = {
  "day-1": {
    "player-1-1": "Ford",
    "chapter-1-2": "BMW"
  },
  "day-2": {
    "player-2-1": "Benz",
    "player-2-2": "KIA",
  },
  "day-3": {
    "player-3-1": "Toyota",
    "player-3-2": "Mazda",
  },
  "day-4": {
    "player-4-1": "Honda",
    "player-4-2": "Nissan",
  },
}

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(cars).forEach((val, index) => {
  var txt = Object.values(cars[val]);
  document.body.innerHTML += `<div class="card-body">${txt}</div>`;
});
```

```css
span {
  background: orange;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to have the keys `day-1`, `day-2` etc. instead of the car names, just replace the `txt` in the second-last line with `val`.

```
document.body.innerHTML += `<div class="card-body">${val}</div>`;
```

Comment: Thanks Jack but this is dumping each nodes values in one place. How can I separate each content then

Comment: What do you mean @MonaCoder?

Comment: For Example the `card-body` first should contains two  elements as span linke `<span>Ford</span><span>BMW</span>` instead of having `Ford,BMW`

Comment: Oh, OK. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Javascript/jQuery to add the `<div class="card-body"></div>` just as needed:
Here is a example:
I your `HTMl`-code add a div with an id:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

In your `Javascript` code:

```
var tds = new Array();
var j = 0;
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(cars).forEach((val, index) => {
  var txt = Object.values(cars[val]);
  tds[++j] = "<div class='card-body'>";
  tds[++j] = "<p>"+ txt.split(',')[0] +"</p>"
  tds[++j] = "<p>"+ txt.split(',')[1] +"</p>"
  tds[++j] = "</div>";
});
$("#result").append(tds.join(''));
```

and you are done.

I used the code provided by [jack-bashford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10221765/jack-bashford) to access the JSON Object without testing it. But it's another problem, you can hopefully solve.